# How to cancel posix mode after "set -o posix"?

Tags: linux, bash

I can not find the answer after googling "how cancel bash posix set -o".

Is there a way to cancel it except using command exit?

Comment: Shooting from the hip, but does `set +o posix` work?

Comment: @Ben Thanks for helping me.

Comment: `set` is a bash builtin command. See: `help set` or `help -m set | less`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`set +o posix`. In general, `-o` turns an option on; `+o` turns it off, to the extent possible. (Turning posix mode off won't retroactively change the startup behaviour, for example.)